# The property 'uid' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

User is not working. I'm not uploading a collection in Firebase

```
try {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
    (email: kEmail.text, password: kPassword.text)
      .then((value) {
    userCollection.doc(value.user.uid).set({
      'userName': kUserName,
      'email': kEmail,
      'password': kPassword,
      'uid': value.user.uid
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  print(err.toString());
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Did the answer by Problematic Dude answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

User can be null. So do null checking first like

```
try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: kEmail.text, password: kPassword.text)
        .then((value) {
      if(value!=null && value.user != null){
         userCollection.doc(value.user.uid).set({
        'userName': kUserName,
        'email': kEmail,
        'password': kPassword,
        'uid': value.user.uid
         });
      }else{
        throw Error();
       }
      
    });
  } catch (err) {
    print(err.toString);
  }
```

or a simple sol will be

```
..
Rest of the code...

userCollection.doc(value.user!.uid)

....Rest of the code //Add ! after user
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to like this

(e.data() as dynamic)['myFieldOne']

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhA7h.png